# CMake, QT Quick & Visual Studio: "qrc:/main.qml:-1 File not found"

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, cmake, qt-quick

I am trying to use `QT Quick` (`QML`) with `Visual Studio 2015` and `CMake`. I started with an example "QT Quick Controls - Gallery" and transfered it to CMake. It works fine in `QT Creator` (using Visual Studio's compiler), but not in Visual Studio (solution generated with `CMake GUI`):

```
QQmlApplicationEngine failed to load component
qrc:/main.qml:-1 File not found
```

I have tried to isolate the problem and found this wonderful example: https://github.com/mattfife/QtQuick-with-cmake, which works (after some modifications) in QT Creator, but has the exactly same problem in Visual Studio.

The `qml.qrc` file is like this:

```
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/">
        <file>main.qml</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

For both environments (QT Creator and Visual Studio), I have in the build directory a file `src/qml.qrc.depends`, whose content is exactly the previous qml file.

The important part in the `main.cpp`:

```
QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
if (engine.rootObjects().isEmpty())
    return -1;
```

The error can be reproduced in QT Creator if I eliminate the next line in the `CMakeLists.txt` file:

```
qt5_add_resources(qml_QRC src/qml.qrc)
```

Any idea of how to solve it or what to try ? By example, I have no idea how to debug this `QQmlApplicationEngine` object.

Comment: You should try to load `":/main.qml"` instead of `"qrc:/main.qml"`. No prefix was declared in your qml.qrc file. Then, you shouldn't have to use one before calling your file.

Comment: @Abrikot No, it doesn't work. Now the second line in the message is `file:///D:/Sources/External/QtQuick-with-cmake/build/:/main.qml:-1 File not found`

Comment: I have currently nothing to test, but it seems to look for your file in the build directory. So, if your `main.qml` file is copied to `D:/Sources/External/QtQuick-with-cmake/build/main.‌​qml`, removing `:/` should work, e.g. `engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("main.qml")));`.

Comment: Well, it does something: `QQmlApplicationEngine failed to load component
file:///D:/Sources/External/QtQuick-with-cmake/build/main.qml:1 le module "QtQuick" n'est pas install?
file:///D:/Sources/External/QtQuick-with-cmake/build/main.qml:2 le module "QtQuick.Window" n'est pas install?`
Sorry for the ... French. 

First two lines in the main.qml are: `import QtQuick 2.3
import QtQuick.Window 2.2`

Comment: But even if this workaround could work, I do not think this is the solution as QT Creator does not need it, apparently.
Besides, there is this generated qrc_qml.cpp file ... shouldn't it do the work?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't know a lot about using Qt with Cmake... After some research, I found these links: [Qt Quick Compiler](http://doc.qt.io/QtQuickCompiler/index.html) and [building with CMake](http://doc.qt.io/QtQuickCompiler/qquickcompiler-building-with-cmake.html). Could they be useful to you?

Comment: QT Creator works well with CMake files, it is what I'm doing now. The problem is CMake using QT in Visual Studio. Stranger thing: even QT Creator uses Visual Studio's compiler ! So it must be some setting somewhere ... I'm using CMake and not QT Creator directly to not force people into QT Creator if they prefer something else (Visual Studio in particular).

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you added a generated file (I assume it's qrc_qml.cpp in your case) into your project. In Visual Studio, when you right-click on qml.qrc, there is a Compile option (or Ctrl+F7). This will generate a cpp file from your qml.qrc. it is usually generated in GeneratedFiles folder.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but unfortunately I do not work "there" anymore. Nevertheless, I see I mention some equivalent example (mattfife on github) that I will try when I will use Visual Studio next time. I hope I won't forget :(